# Composition proxy target must implement at least one interface

Tags: c#, .net, spring, wcf

I have a simple WCF service but when I try to open it in the browser I get this error:

Composition proxy target must implement at least one interface

Markup code

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Mvm.SATWeb.ServicesLiquidez.Service.WSRiesgoLiquidez"  Factory="Spring.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory" CodeBehind="WSRiesgoLiquidez.svc.cs" %>
```

IWSRiesgoLiquidez.cs

```
namespace Mvm.SATWeb.ServicesLiquidez.Service
{
    // NOTE: If you change the interface name "IWSEnvioTerceros" here, you must also update the reference to "IWSEnvioTerceros" in Web.config.
    [ServiceContract]
    interface IWSRiesgoLiquidez    
    {

        [OperationContract]
        ResultadoOperacionLiquidez consultaIngresosEgresosPuntosDeAtencion(string USUARIO, string CLAVE, string CODIGORED, string FECHA, string HORAINICIAL, string HORAFINAL);

        [OperationContract]
        ResultadoOperacionLiquidez consultaValorRealPuntoDeAtencion(string USUARIO, string CLAVE, string CODIGORED, string CODIGOPUNTOATENCION);

        [OperationContract]
        ResultadoOperacionLiquidez consultaValorRealPorPuntosDeatencion(string USUARIO, string CLAVE, string CODIGORED);



    }
}
```

The implementation: WSRiesgoLiquidez.cs

```
namespace Mvm.SATWeb.ServicesLiquidez.Service
{

    public class WSRiesgoLiquidez : IWSRiesgoLiquidez
    {


        public ResultadoOperacionLiquidez consultaIngresosEgresosPuntosDeAtencion(string USUARIO, string CLAVE, string CODIGORED, string FECHA, string HORAINICIAL, string HORAFINAL)
        {
            ResultadoOperacionLiquidez respuesta = new ResultadoOperacionLiquidez();
            IServicioMaestros ServicioMaestros = SATWebServiceLocator<IServicioMaestros>.ObtenerServicio();





            try
            {

                using (var riesLiq = new Mvm.SATWeb.ServicesLiquidez.Comun.BusinessDelegate.RiesgoLiqBD())
                {
                  //  respuesta.Retorno = riesLiq.consultaIngresosEgresosPuntosDeAtencion(HORAINICIAL, HORAFINAL);

                    //EnvioTO objLiq = riesLiq.consultaIngresosEgresosPuntosDeAtencion(HORAINICIAL, HORAFINAL);

                    respuesta = riesLiq.consultaIngresosEgresosPuntosDeAtencion(HORAINICIAL, HORAFINAL);


                    respuesta.EjecucionExitosa = true;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                respuesta.EjecucionExitosa = false;
                respuesta.MensajeValidacion = RemoveLocalizationString(ex.Message);

            }

            return respuesta;

        }
        public ResultadoOperacionLiquidez consultaValorRealPuntoDeAtencion(string USUARIO, string CLAVE, string CODIGORED, string CODIGOPUNTOATENCION)
        {
            ResultadoOperacionLiquidez respuesta = new ResultadoOperacionLiquidez();
            return respuesta;
        }





        public ResultadoOperacionLiquidez consultaValorRealPorPuntosDeatencion(string USUARIO, string CLAVE, string CODIGORED)
        {
            ResultadoOperacionLiquidez respuesta = new ResultadoOperacionLiquidez();
            return respuesta;
        }
        private string RemoveLocalizationString(string p)
        {
            string strMensaje = String.Empty;
            strMensaje = p.Replace("[", "").Replace(", es-CO]", "");
            return strMensaje;
        }


    }
}
```

Then in my web.config I have:

```
  <sectionGroup name="spring">
      <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler, Spring.Core" />
      <section name="objects" type="Spring.Context.Support.DefaultSectionHandler, Spring.Core" />
    </sectionGroup>

  </configSections>
  <!-- Configuración de spring con los servicios Web -->


  <spring>
    <context>
       Servicios de seguridad, logging, multilenguaje, etc. 
      <resource uri="~/Servicios/Infraestructura.config" />
       La declaracion de los servicios de negocio (Los BO) 
      <resource uri="~/Servicios/ServiciosNegocio.config" />
    </context>
  </spring>
```

On ServiciosNegocios.config I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
  <description>Declaracion de objetos de negocio</description>





  <!--Objetos de negocio - Seguridad-->
  <object id="SATWebSeguridadTarget" type="Mvm.SATWeb.Core.Seguridad.Modelo.Negocio.ServicioSeguridad, Mvm.SATWeb.Core">
  </object>
  <!--Proxy - Seguridad-->
  <object id="SATWebSeguridadService"
      type="Spring.Aop.Framework.ProxyFactoryObject">
    <property name="target">
      <ref object="SATWebSeguridadTarget"/>
    </property>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
      <list>
        <value>MethodInterceptor</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </object>

  <object id="Mvm.SATWeb.ServicesLiquidez.Service.WSRiesgoLiquidezTarget"
            type="Mvm.SATWeb.ServicesLiquidez.Service.WSRiesgoLiquidez, Mvm.SATWeb.ServicesLiquidez">
  </object>

  <object id="Mvm.SATWeb.ServicesLiquidez.Service.WSRiesgoLiquidez"
        type="Spring.Aop.Framework.ProxyFactoryObject">
    <property name="target">
      <ref object="Mvm.SATWeb.ServicesLiquidez.Service.WSRiesgoLiquidezTarget"/>
    </property>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
      <list>
        <value>MethodInterceptor</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </object>

</objects>
```

And Infraestructure.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
<description>Declaracion e integracion de servicios de infraestructura.</description>

  <!-- AOP Advices -->
  <object id="MethodInterceptor" type="Mvm.SATWeb.Core.Comun.AOP.MethodInterceptor, Mvm.SATWeb.Core" />

  <!-- Servicio SIDUtil -->
  <object id="UtilService" type="Mvm.SATWeb.ServicesLiquidez.Comun.Helpers.SATWebUtil, Mvm.SATWeb.ServicesLiquidez">
  </object>

  <!-- configuracion de mensajes -->
  <object id="messageSource" type="Spring.Context.Support.ResourceSetMessageSource, Spring.Core">
    <property name="ResourceManagers">
      <list>
        <value>Resources.Mensajes, App_GlobalResources</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </object>

  <object id="LocalizacionLenguajeService"
          type="Mvm.Localizacion.Lenguaje.ClientAPI.LenguajeServiceSpringResx, Mvm.Localizacion.Lenguaje.ClientAPI">
  </object>



</objects>
```

The detailed error is this:

> Composition proxy target must implement at least one interface.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Composition proxy target
>   must implement at least one interface.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentException: Composition proxy target must implement at least
>   one interface.]
>   Spring.Proxy.CompositionProxyTypeBuilder.BuildProxyType() +125
>   Spring.ServiceModel.Support.ServiceProxyTypeBuilder.BuildProxyType()
>   +41    Spring.ServiceModel.SpringServiceHost.CreateServiceType(String serviceName, IApplicationContext applicationContext) +173
>   Spring.ServiceModel.SpringServiceHost..ctor(String serviceName,
>   IApplicationContext applicationContext, Uri[] baseAddresses) +43
>   Spring.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String
>   reference, Uri[] baseAddresses) +141
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath) +693
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath) +42
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath) +479